# how to use Keras LSTM model to android?

Tags: android, python, keras, lstm

I used the keras to create the LSTM model and I've already trained models that are stored as `models.h5` files.

I want to know how to predict the model in the Android studio.

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Please have a look on [Tensorflow Lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite) and to convert your keras model to tensorflow lite follow [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lite/TFLiteConverter). I am not sure about LSTM model but you can research about it.

Comment: ^ this guy is right. Keras models can be deployed to android with tensorflow lite.

Comment: Do not attempt to use Tensorflow Lite to run an LSTM Keras model on Android. The converters do not support Keras's LSTM format. There are proposed workarounds but they are difficult to find and implement, and are vulnerable to compatibility issues between versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [deeplearning4j](https://deeplearning4j.org). You can set up deeplearning4j in Android Studio following the instructions [here](https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/deeplearning4j-android).

Trained Keras models can be imported directly into deeplearning4j using the Keras model import functionality described [here](https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/keras-import-overview). You can then perform predictions with the trained model in Java.